# Does kiddushin work if the couple don't understand the implications?

Tags: halacha, marriage, maseches-kiddushin

According to the first Mishna of Kiddushin, if I understand correctly, marriage is effectively a legal contract where the man takes "ownership" of the woman with her consent.  [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/139123/2642) to a previous question explains that according to Rambam, this "ownership" is effectively ownership of the rights to intimate relations with her.

As far as I understand, in halacha, a contract is null and void if either party doesn't understand what they are agreeing to (sorry, I don't have a reference for this, but I am pretty sure I have heard it a number of times).  In the case of marriage, according to Rambam's opinion, I'm sure that not everyone getting married is aware of this (and perhaps some women would not even agree to it if they were!) These days, I suspect that this is not what most people understand marriage to be (whether they are correct or not).  Additionally, does this not present a problem in terms of the woman giving her consent to marry? (which Gemara Kiddushin does specify is required, although I can't recall the reference) - I'm not sure if this is technically a separate question or not.

Does this not present a very large problem in terms of the validity of kiddushin for people who aren't aware of this?  I realise that the intimate relations themselves also serve to establish the marriage, but as far as I understand, this is not something that we practice these days (at least officially).

Comment: It's unlikely that almost anyone ever fully understands every detail of marital law before engaging in it. That's true in the secular world as well.

Comment: What percentage of people think that she can be with other men post-kiddushin?

Comment: @DoubleAA true, but that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @AKA that is a good point, but there may be an argument that there is a difference between restricting her from other men and giving her rights to her husband

Comment: @moses supposes The specific example (based on Rambam) has virtually no practical implications (possibly zero), so I can't imagine anyone would object.

Comment: @moses why not?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well for a start, she may think that marital relations are purely her right and not her husband's

Comment: @Moses and why does that mean I didn't answer the question

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, thought you were asking me a different question (on what AKA said).  I meant that I don't see whether it is relevant whether no one understands it.  Don't both parties need to fully understand it in order for it to become binding?

Comment: @MosesSupposes Clearly not since then nearly nobody would be able to enter into nearly any contract. There's a reason we have lawyers and courts. People agree to engage with an existing legal construct without fully understanding it. This happens all the time in every culture everywhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA This feels quite significant to me - if we go off what Rambam is saying, that seems to be the main halachic function of kiddushin, and if a woman doesn't understand that is what she is agreeing to then that doesn't seem like a minor detail to me?